# .textContent .innerHTML, not updating text content, WORKED at First, Then Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, html

I was testing if one could use javascript to put the `option` value in the `select` element instead of writing out the HTML code which would be hectic.

Initially when I tried it, it worked at first, but then it started from year 2010, and I wanted the `option value` to have **year** then I changed the code, and it didn't work, i changed it back to how it was before, still it didn't work, then I tried it again and again and it didn't work, kept on changing the code to see if it works on the HTML page, but it didn't. (but worked perfectly fine  on the chrome javascript console every time I changed it).
Please what can I do to make it work?

placed the script at the end of the page, it didn't work, then also tried it at the beginning, then lastly after the `id` I selected. all didn't work.

```js
function yearDate() {
  let mydate = [`<option>Year<option>`],
    number = 2010;
  for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    mydate.push(`<option>${number}</option>`);
    number -= 1;
  }
  return mydate.join("");
}

let myNewDate = yearDate();

let elYear = document.getElementById("year");
elYear.textContent = myNewDate;
```

```html
<select id='year'></select>
```

I'm using

> Bracket Release 1.10 build 1.10.0-17483 (release 024bee940)  build
>   timestamp: Tue Jul 04 2017 23:07:56 GMT-0700

and

> Chrome Browser Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)
>   to test the code.

the Code works fine with Javascript console to output the desired results.

Though I'm new to Javascript, and programming in general. 
Please Help out with this.

Comment: Please, paste code from your screenshots into your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code and markup and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I've pasted code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `elYear.textContent = myNewDate;` should be changed to `elYear.innerHMTL = myNewDate;` if you are trying to populate a select menu with an HTML string.

```js
const startDate = 2010;
function yearDate(startYear) {
  let year = startYear;
  let options = `<option>Year<option>`;
  for (let x = 0; x <= 100; x++) {
    options += `<option>${year}</option>`;
    year -= 1;
  }
  return options;
}

let myNewDate = yearDate(startDate);

let elYear = document.getElementById("year");
elYear.innerHTML = myNewDate;
elYear.value = 2010 - 100;

document.getElementById('year').addEventListener('change', function(){
  const value = this.value;
  document.getElementById('selectedyear').innerText = `The value is: ${value}`;
});
```

```html
<select id='year'></select>
<div id='selectedyear'></div>
```

Comment: I tried innerHTML too, it didn’t work, I explained that in the question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get the select element value into a div as text? Its unclear in your question.

Comment: @Pachino I updated my answer to include adding the selected year into a div as text.

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` might work in some browsers, but `option` elements can't have HTML, the correct property to set the text to an option is `text`.

Comment: I’m trying to use javascript to get the select element output 100 years from 2010, instead of using the option element to output it to the page. the Javascript code outputs the option value as wanted, and as it would have been in the html document.

Comment: You want `.value` then. I updated my example. If you set `selectElement.value = myVal` it will update the element to show that value